# VB or C# for SQL Server - Just learning SQL Server (going from Access)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005

I am just getting into SQL Server, and I have some experience with MS Access an Visual Basic (well VB within Access anyway).

So I am trying to acquire materials (books, etc) to learn how to program sql server, and I am wondering if I should go the C# route instead of visual basic for sql server?? not super familiar with c# (though i am sure i can pick it up), to know which is better??

i would like to start with code to design UI and forms, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accessing SQL Server either C# or VB.NET will be pretty much identical.

Choose the one you are more familiar with.

Comment: Yeah I think I may have to start out with VB, as to not overwhelm myself since its all brand new. I can learn the C# and C++ later after I am more familiar with SQL Server in general! Thanks Mitch!

Comment: So my next question...where do you think I should begin. I downloaded the Express Edition and VS 2008. Played with them a bit....do you suggest books for learning or are there good websites? Thanks! much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It makes no difference which you choose.
The general ideea is use watever you CAN use.
But in general C# is much more widely used than VB. If you learn C# and you get a VB project you could easily modify it. But if you know VB and get a C# application, then it would be much harder.
It's good to know VB but it'smuch better if you know both.

Don't take this seriously but it is said that VB is for people who don't want to learn programming.( :) )

Comment: added note: today i worked on a VB.NET application (i am a C# developer) and i just learned a couple of new swear words. Any way you go... remember always to name your variables, functions, procedures accordingly to what they do... if you have a function that gets some data from the database name it GetDataFromDatabase... i beg you for the good of all programmers including yourself...

Answer (score 1):

For creating "UI and forms" you will need to learn some C#.

Have a look at the videos here to get started: http://www.asp.net/get-started/

Good luck

Comment: you can create UI and forms just as easily in VB.NET !

Comment: You can indeed use VB.NET or C# as Mitch Wheat notes his comment and his answer. While I personally recommend C# (or IronPython), I was attempting to point out that "UI and forms" are not part of SQL server like they were in MS Access and provide a link to videos for help getting started.

Comment: Acutally I appreciate that considering that if interacting form controls with database is so much different, then perhaps I will start to learn with VB, and move to C#/C++ later. I have Visual Studio 2008....but like I said its all very very new to me....and it obviously looks tons different than Access. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I found that VB.NET was a little easier to get my head around then C#.  I too had some experience with VB and ASP Classic, C# just looks difficult, although I am sure it is not any more difficult to learn.

Either way, there are plenty of resources online for both languages and if you ever run into any issues there are converters that can convert code from one to the other.

I think it is going to be a preference and you should always do what you feel most comftorable with as it is you who will be writting the code and not us.

Good luck with which ever way you go.

Matt

Comment: thanks Matt! I too learned VB in the beginning because its all i needed for Access (and Office products in general). But since we are going to move into SQL Server at work, I figured I should learn C#.

Do you have an example of VB to C# convertor site? Thanks man! That will actually help me out a lot!

Comment: I use this one: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/.
I am not sure, I may be ignorant or not noticed, but I look after my works SQL Servers and havent encountered any issues with no knowing C#.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd recommend C# over VB.Net as the syntax/code style in C# is similar to a lot of other languages: C, Java, Perl (OO).

Both will work with SQL Server and there's plenty of books on both languages, C# will can set you up to learn a lot more languages = better career option IMHO.

Comment: very good point! so my next question become what are the best resources for learning it (specifically tied to SQL server if possible ). Thanks!